# How to know the android apps installation mode?

Tags: android, apk

I wanted to know that,Is it possible to know whether the android app is installed through website, through Google play or has been distributed by the users??

Comment: You can find all apps list which you install using google play store https://play.google.com/apps . others are distributed by the users

Comment: Hi Nirav Ranpara i to know if the installation is done from play or other source i need to find that first time of installation

Comment: I dont think this is possible

Comment: ok what if i dnt want to upload it on google play and only on my website then is there any way to know that the installation is done?

Comment: Not at all . only play.google is way , OR you can put counter on your instillation button on web site but this is not a right way

Comment: I want the app to be installed from my website but the distribution should not be allowed of the app